# What is $\forall_x\exists_yA(x,y)$ where A(x): X is pointing to Y?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am new to predicate logic and am just learning about it; I encountered this problem on a quiz and was disconcerted by how I was supposed to answer it.

My answer for the quiz was: **For every x, there exists a y where x points to y.**
I still don't know if I was correct.

I had a few confusions regarding this logic:

If x points to itself, would that be considered satisfactory to this logic? Can x point to multiple y values? Do all x's need to point to the same y value. Can a value for x also be a value for y, where it points to itself?

There was a question after this: $$\exists_y\forall_xA(x,y)$$

In this case, I answered: **There is some y, where all x point to y.** Which in my mind meant that x would only point to y.

So again, I was confused by my overthinking. Does y need to point to itself, or can y point to some other x?

Comment: Are you asking about the distinction between the order of the quantifiers? I.e $\forall x \exists y$ vs $\exists y \forall x$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall x \exists y A(x,y)$$ colloquially says that “each $x$ has a $y$ to point at.” That $y$ could be $x$. It also says nothing about each $x$ pointing to the same $y$; they could be different.

Conversely, $$\exists y \forall x A(x,y)$$ colloquially says that “some $y$ is pointed at by each $x$”. Now $y$ is included in the statement “by each $x$”… so yes! $y$ is pointing at itself in this case.

If we wanted each $x$ to *only* point at this $y$ we would have to quantify as follows:
$$\exists y \forall x (A(x,y) \land \forall z (A(x,z) \rightarrow z=y))$$ can you see why?

Comment: For the first predicate logic, can x point to multiple y's?

Comment: If a $x$ pointed to *multiple* $y$, would it be true that $x$ had a $y$ to point at?

Comment: Yes - it would be true that x had a y to point at

Comment: So the answer to your question is YES! :)

Comment: Thank You so much for the help! I am still somewhat confused by the second predicate logic since you said that not all x need to point to the same y, would the second be the same as the first predicate logic?

Comment: The moral of the story here is the order of the quantifiers. For the former case ( $\forall x \exists y$) it is not necessarily true that each x points to the same y. For the latter case, we are saying that there is a y that each x points at. That is, each x *is* pointing to the same y.

Comment: hmm...I am somewhat confused, does ∃y∀xA(x,y) mean that all x have to def point to the same y? I am sorry if this seems repetitive, I just want to clarify. Thank you again!

Comment: Maybe switching up the language a bit would help. Let $A(x,y)$ mean “person x loves person y.” Then $\forall x \exists y A(x,y)$ would mean “Everybody loves somebody”. Nothing more, nothing less. In comparison, $\exists y \forall x A(x,y)$  would say “somebody is loved by everyone.” So if you are the aforementioned “somebody” then everyone loves *you*. The same unique *you*.

Comment: oooh, that helped quite actually. Thank you so much for all this help! I hope you have a nice day tomorrow, Good night!